# Sometimes I see $\int$ there but no $d$ follows. Why?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

In my opinion, the mathematical symbols $\int$ and $d$ should always appear together to represent an integral form, such as

\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^{x_1} e^x dx = e^{x_1}-e^{x_0}
\end{align}

In the LHS, $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}$ and $dx$ construct an integral for the variable of integration $x$ over $[x_0,x_1]$. However, I do see the integral sign $\int$ alone without $d$ sometimes in some math formula, for example

\begin{align}
\int_{\partial \Omega} \omega = \int_\Omega d\omega
\end{align}

The LHS of this classic Stokes' formula does not contain $d$. Why the $\int$ can appear without $d$? I do observe many other cases like this, typically in real analysis and differential geometry. Do they just omit $d$ and consider the variable of integration in default?

Comment: Some books use the integral symbol to actually denote a small sum,  i had one of these books, my blood presure went sky high

Comment: Note that $\omega$ is not a function but a differential form. If you prefer, it already has the appropriate amount of "d" baked into it

Comment: Because $\omega$ in that case is a "differential form," and a differential form already has "d" in it. So it already contains the $dx$ or $dx\,dy$. The real oddity is that $d\omega$ on the right side is actually an operation applied to the differential form $\omega$ which.

Answer (score 6):

To put it simply (and maybe a little harshly), your opinion is wrong.

Given a function $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ (let's stay in intervals just to simplify the discussion), the symbol $\int_{[a,b]}f$ is completely well-defined (be it Riemann, Lebesgue or whatever integration theory you are using). For instance, your first equation is
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\exp=\exp(x_1)-\exp(x_0).$$

In fact, it is arguably more accurate than its "brother" $\int_{[a,b]} f(x) dx$, which props up in things like $\int_{[a,b]} x^2dx$ for example. Such notation is mostly used for computational (e.g. applications of Fubini, change of variables etc) and pedagogical purposes, because otherwise we would need to write
$$\int_{[a,b]} (x \mapsto x^2).$$
instead of
$$\int_{[a,b]}x^2dx$$
among other things.

The "$d$" in Stokes's theorem is another thing altogether, and its conception is much more elaborate than some texts/people imply by [not even wrongly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) saying
that it formalizes/generalizes the "dx" appearing in integration (which actually doesn't appear and is a notational fantasy).

Comment: If you emphasize so heavily that $\int_{[a,b]}f$ is well-defined, then why do you use the notation $\int_a^bf$ instead in your first equation? Is it because with $\int_{[a,b]}f$ the equation is not actually true in general (when $a>b$)?

Comment: @Rahul Just to mirror OP actually. If $a>b$, we can define $\int_{[a,b]} f=-\int_{[b,a]} f$ (as is done due to convenience).

Comment: +1 for the beautiful answer which clears many misconceptions students have. Integral depends on function and the interval over which we want to integrate. Nothing more needs to be included in notation.